# $.ajax is not a function / firebase functions

Tags: jquery, ajax, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm developing something for college
I'm trying to setup a cron job with the help of a function in firebase. this function gets some info with an API request, and does something with that info.

I did the normal setup on the node.js environment.

```
npm install firebase-admin
npm install firebase-functions
npm install jquery
```

after that I started coding the `index.js` and here's the code:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)

const ref = admin.database().ref()
var $ = require("jquery")

exports.llamada = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  $.ajax({
      url : "https://api.wunderground.com/api/*******/geolookup/conditions/q/zmw:00000.287.80028.json",
      dataType : "jsonp",
      success : function(parsed_json) {
      var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];
      var temp_c = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_c'];
      var solarradiation = parsed_json['current_observation']['solarradiation'];
      var condicion = parsed_json['current_observation']['icon'];
    }
  });
    function writeWeatherData(location, temp_c, solarradiation, condicion) {
    firebase.database().ref('datos/').set({
      localizacion: location,
      temperatura: temp_c,
      radiacion_solar: solarradiation,
      clima: condicion
    });
  }
});
```

and also I added the next to my package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^5.4.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I deployed the function and everything was good. I deployed with both commands:

`firebase deploy --only functions`
`firebase deploy`

which deployed the function correctly in both cases.

after that I made a request so I could test the function and got and error

> Error: could not handle the request.

then I checked the logs on firebase functions console and this is what it shows:

`TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at exports.llamada.functions.https.onRequest (/user_code/index.js:12:5)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:26:41)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:635:7
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:619:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)`

am I not requesting the jquery module properly? because it seems like the compiler is not understanding $.ajax

any kind of help is appreciated!

Comment: You seem to be missing an import and a call after you require jquery - check out the docs [here](https://github.com/UncoolAJ86/node-jquery).

I suggest that you try the [request library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) because jquery was originally designed for frontend code.

Comment: I'm still getting the hang of request, but it seems like it's the right direction. thanks @KevinLee